# CSS styles gone after alert message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

On my page I have a form with many input boxes and select multiple. I'm using PHP to access a database. Now, when I click on my submit button I check if my query was successful, if that's not the case I send an error message with alert. For that I'm doing this code:

```
if(!mysqli_query($ligacao, $SQL)){

     echo '<script language="javascript">';
     echo 'alert("'.$error_msg.'")';
     echo '</script>';

     return;
}
```

Notice, I do the `return;` because I have another queries after this code and I don't want them to execute in case there's an error on this first one.

This part is all working, I get the message and the code after isn't done. The thing is, when I click "ok" on the alert message, the message is gone but the CSS of selects are gone. Instead of seeing the CSS style I have for the selects I see them on plain text and with no style. To get back to normal I need to refresh the page. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Does your html src include a link to the css file after calling the alert?

Comment: Probably not. How can i include a link to the css after an alert calling?

Comment: First of all `$error_msg` won't even be evaluated inside single quotes. And if it did you'd need quotes around whatever it contains: `echo "alert('$error_msg')"`. Finally, it probably shouldn't be your database backends responsibility how error messages are presented. Thats pretty bad design.

Comment: I copied the wrong code, sorry. Indeed the echo wouldn't work. Already edited

Comment: If that's not in a function `return` will exit the entire script (assuming it's all mashed together in one script) at that point, which is quite likely to bork something; since PHP runs before the code in the client (HTML, JS, CSS) it's likely you're truncating your client-side code.

Comment: So, instead of return what should i use to stop the code? die() ?

Comment: @cesarPR - that would be even worse; you don't *want* to stop the code, you want it to run with conditions; try ditching the `return` and using `elseif` on your other conditions.

Comment: Ok, i can make that work. I can put the followwing code to run only if this code didn't gave an error. So the real problem is, why is the css gone

Comment: The problem was actually the return. After i removed it and arranged the code with if else conditions the problem no longer exists. Why do you think that was the reason? Maybe because i was ending the code on my php, so before the html, css, etc would execute right? You wanna write an answer and i accept it for reputation?

Comment: "Why do you think that was the reason?" It was already explained to you in the earlier comments - your return statement stopped your PHP from executing, which stopped the rest of the content of your page from being sent to the browser. No doubt this included the links to CSS files.

Comment: True, write an answer if you want. So we can close the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `return` statement stops your PHP from executing, which stopped the rest of the content of your page from being sent to the browser. No doubt this included the links to CSS files.

Instead make use of `if` and `else` statements to show/hide only the content you want, rather than terminating the entire script.

Comment: The use of the return was indeed the problem. Thanks